# Using group by with left join and IN yields empty result

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I have two tables: `invitees` and `invitee_information`. invitees belong to `events` (third table event_id is a foreign key in `invitees` table).

I want to get the total count of invitees per event for which there is no information available yet (no record in the `invitee_information` table).

When I write the query using only one `event_id` in the where clause and anti-join pattern (IS NULL for `invitee_id` column to filter for rows having no information saved) the count is returned as expected for that given event_id:

```
SELECT COUNT(i.id)
FROM invitees i
LEFT JOIN invitee_information ii 
ON ii.invitee_id = i.id
WHERE ii.invitee_id IS NULL AND i.`event_id` = 18571 AND i.`invitation_sent` = 1;
```

Now in order to optimize the query to get this count data at DB level for multiple event_ids instead of getting this in a loop for each event_id, I used IN and passed multiple event_ids and used GROUP_BY `event_id`.

Expected result should be (if there is no data saved in `invitee_information` table for event_id 18569 :

```
event_id | count(i.id)
18569    |          0
```

But query result is always empty. My updated query is:

```
SELECT i.`event_id`, COUNT(i.id)
FROM invitees i
LEFT JOIN invitee_information ii 
ON i.id = ii.invitee_id
WHERE ii.invitee_id IS NULL AND i.`event_id` IN(18569,18571) AND i.`invitation_sent` = 1
GROUP BY i.`event_id`;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could imagine this happening is if you have internationalization settings such that `,` means a decimal point.  You can easily test this using:

```
SELECT i.`event_id`, COUNT(i.id)
FROM invitees i LEFT JOIN
     invitee_information ii 
     ON i.id = ii.invitee_id
WHERE ii.invitee_id IS NULL AND
      (i.`event_id` = 18569 OR i.`event_id` = 18571) AND
      i.`invitation_sent` = 1
GROUP BY i.`event_id`;
```

If this works, then at least we have identified the problem.  I think a space then works:

```
SELECT i.`event_id`, COUNT(i.id)
FROM invitees i LEFT JOIN
     invitee_information ii 
     ON i.id = ii.invitee_id
WHERE ii.invitee_id IS NULL AND
      i.`event_id` IN (18569, 18571) AND
      i.`invitation_sent` = 1
GROUP BY i.`event_id`;
```

I should note that you probably want `COUNT(ii.invitee_id)` in the `SELECT` rather than `COUNT(i.id)`.  The latter will never return `0`.

EDIT:

Perhaps the two *events* are not in the `invitees` table.  Assuming you have an events table, then something like this:

```
SELECT e.event_id, COUNT(i.id)
FROM events e LEFT JOIN
     invitees i
     ON i.event_id = e.event_id AND
        i.invitation_sent = 1 LEFT JOIN
     invitee_information ii 
     ON i.id = ii.invitee_id 
WHERE ii.invitee_id IS NULL AND
      e.event_id IN (18569, 18571) AND
GROUP BY e.event_id;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. No, both queries yielded an empty result. Also, could this be possible that my first query with only single event_id will always return 0 as count?

Comment: I am counting invitees.id because I want to count all invitee for which there is no information provided yet. No information provided means that no record in `invitee_information` table with invitee_id as foreign key.

Comment: @AliMalik . . . Is the problem that both invitees are not in `invitees`?  That is not how I understood your question, but that might be what you are trying to ask.

Comment: Invitees are there, in the `invitees` table. But their information may not be available yet.  So I want to get those for which there is no entry in info table.
Thank you for discussing btw.